# Why is my file unchanged when I switch branches in git?

Tags: git

I create a file, new_file.dat, in the master branch and then switch to a new existing branch named 'branch'. After the switch, I see that the file is still there:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ emacs new_file.dat
$ cat new_file.dat 
Hello
$ git checkout branch
Switched to branch 'branch'
$ cat new_file.dat 
Hello
```

I do not understand this behavior: isn't git supposed to replace all files with those of 'branch' after the switch? Why is new_file.dat still there?

Comment: That is clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you switch branches, files that are not tracked by Git will remain untouched. Since Git does not know about `new_file.dat`, it will not just delete it.

If you did:

```
git checkout master
echo "Hello" > new_file.dat
git add new_file.dat
git checkout branch
```

The file `new_file.dat` would still be staged and present; you could commit it to the `branch` branch if you wanted.

If instead you did:

```
git checkout master
echo "Hello" > new_file.dat
git add new_file.dat
git commit -m "add new_file.dat"
git checkout branch
```

The file would disappear, since it's now tracked by Git and not on `branch`.

If you want to find out which files Git currently tracks, use `git ls-files`.